# Using Google Analytics to track impressions of shpreadsheet+appscript as UI and BE instead of a website

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to use apps script as the backend of a spreadhsheet (as the UI. Both serve as a complete website sort of) and track the impressions or click on the spreadsheet buttons.

I want to call GA4 from apps script for that.

Googling it shows `Using Google Apps Script to fetch data from your Google Analytics account` but I want the other way arround..

Also, I don't have a website html (just the spreadsheet as an UI).
So this [guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itmDX.png) isn't exactly what I need.

I have an apps-script that I want to impression count in Google-Analytics.

I have created a new GA account + data stream.

Copied it's `measurement id` and put it in my app-script code:

```
/**
 * Function to track all (internal/external) usage
 * @param {string} page tracked
 */
function sendGA(page) {
  var cid = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(Utilities.computeDigest(
      Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256,
      ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()));
  try {
    var data = {
      'v': '1',
      'tid': 'G-9S9...',
      'z': Math.floor(Math.random()*10E7),
      't':'pageview',
      'dl': SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() + '/' + page,
      'cid': cid
    };
    var payload = Object.keys(data).map(
      function(key) {
        return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
      }
    ).join('&');
    var options = {
      'method' : 'POST',
      'payload' : payload
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', options);
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

[image]

and

[image]

These were my installation steps, have I missed anything?

The `measurement id` goes in here? `'tid': 'G-9S9...',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on articles I'm seeing (they may be outdated), `tid` makes use of tracking ID (e.g. `UA-1234-1`) that is generated when ticking "Create a Universal Analytics property" when creating the property under `Show advanced options`.

I'm seeing similar links that tracks the views instead and is using the pattern `UA-xxxx-x` in `tid`. You are using GA4 so it provides measurement ID instead. Try universal analytics if it works and provide the tracking id on the `tid`.

[image: sample]

#### References:

- [How to Track Google Spreadsheet Views with Google Analytics](https://www.labnol.org/internet/track-google-spreadsheets/29107/)
- [Tracking Google Sheet views with Google Analytics using GA Beacon (and a Google Apps Script Measurement Protocol snippet)](https://hawksey.info/blog/2014/02/tracking-google-sheet-views-with-google-analytics/)
- [Tracking ID and property number](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7372977)
- [Set up Analytics for a website (Universal Analytics)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10269537?hl=en)

Comment: Btw, is there any other property to use in the payload json object to populate the measurement-id?

Comment: Hi @EladBenda, I wasn't able to find anything but [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events). Got this from [event builder](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/)

Comment: Thanks, what do you think I should fill in the website url if I'm trying to track a spreadsheet which creates a new copy for each access?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B86j.png